# android : implementing complex ArrayAdapter item with ability switch the views inside the row

Tags: java, android, custom-controls, android-arrayadapter

I need to build quite complex row in the ArrayAdapter:

[image]

So when the menu in the right corner of the row is clicked or swipted, new view with 3 buttons appearing. And I can turn them back just swiping it back.

I've built a lot of ArrayAdapters, but never had deal with something like that.

Should I use  tag, or just inflating the view ? How and where should I handle the button clicks on the buttons ?

Please help who had experience with something like this, will appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would using this library which does exactly what you want: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Basically the best way is to create a view holder class and use it to be stored into the view tag.
on every call of getView you can then check if the view != null and reuse your tag which is your holder.
Obviously you need to set a new listener because they are supposed to do a different action.
You do all this into the getView method